# Highlight partial duplicates same column

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking to highlight partial duplicates, Column B will have data that is either a single number or multiple numbers separated with a '/'. I can currently get cells with single numbers to highlight if there's a duplicate. I trying to get cells that have multiple numbers to match with cells with single numbers

Example, cell B4 contains 'valueA' , B7 contains 'valueB/valueA' , B8 contains 'valueA/valueC' and B10 contains 'valueA/valueD/valueE' I would like all 4 cells to highlight the same colour

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following CF rule applied to the range B:B

```
=(B1<>"")*(index(sum(n(countif(split(B:B,"/"),split(B1,"/"))>1))>0))
```

Comment: Seems to be working if the matching number is in front of the '/' but doesn't highlight the cell if the matching number is after the '/'

Comment: I edited my answer, if that doesn't work either please consider sharing a sample sheet.

Answer (score 0):

if you are targeting `12` use:

```
=REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(B1), "12")
```

[image]